# Example of an irreducible component with an open set of infinitely many codimension 2 (codimension 3) orbits

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups, quiver

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristics $0$. Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional (associative and unital) algebra over $\mathbb{K}$. Assume there is a quiver $Q=(Q_0,Q_1)$, where $Q_0$ is the set of vertices and $Q_1$ is the set of arrows, associated to $A$, i.e., $A\cong\mathbb{K}Q/I$, with $0 \neq I\subset \mathbb{K}Q$ is an admissible ideal. Further assume that the algebra $A$ is such that the quiver $Q$ is acyclic.

For a dimension vector $\beta$, the representation space
$$
    \mathrm{rep}_{\beta}(Q,I):=\biggl\lbrace M\in\prod_{a\in Q_1}\mathrm{Mat}_{\beta(ha)\times\beta(ta)}(\mathbb{K}) \;\bigg|\; \text{$M(r) = 0$ for all $r \in I$}\biggr\rbrace
$$
parametrizes $\beta$-dimensional representations of $(Q,I)$.
The linear algebraic group
$$
    \mathrm{GL}_{\beta}:=\prod_{x\in Q_0}\mathrm{GL}_{\beta(x)}(\mathbb{K})
$$
acts on $\mathrm{rep}_{\beta}(Q,I)$ by change of basis.

If I consider the quiver which looks like a commutative square and impose the commutativity relation, and consider the representation space with dimension vector $(1,1,1,1)$, then the representation space is an orbit closure, i.e., open orbit of codimension $0$.

[image]

The representation space $\mathrm{rep}_{\beta}(Q,I)$ is again irreducible and it has an open set of infinitely many codimension $1$ orbits of $M_{\lambda}$’s.

Now, I’m wondering what would be an example of an acyclic quiver with relations such that the representation space $\mathrm{rep}_{\beta}(Q,I)$ has an irreducible component $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ has an open (dense) set of infinitely many codimension $2$ orbits, for an appropriate dimension vector $\beta$? What about codimension $3$?

This is important to me. I would be extremely grateful for your help.

Comment: Cross posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/436788/338456

Comment: [Please don't cross-post this quickly](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16290).